# Execute code after an 'assert' in case of AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, assertion

I'm testing a function which its main purpose is to allocate a file to a folder received in the parameters of this function. To do this, I create a empty file in my root folder and test for some different parameters for path. To be more explicit, here's a example:

```py
alocate_file('folder1','folder2','folder3', 'file.txt')
```

This line will result in this allocation:

root/Downloads/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.txt

Some extra characteristics of my function: The Downloads folder is implicit, it receive a list as a parameter and assumes that the last string in the list is the file.

### My problem

After I test this function, I delete the  empty file (created only for the test purpose) and all the folders that my function creates. This is done using shutil.rmtree **after** the assert, and here lies the problem. **When the test fails,** it raises a *AssertionError* and those folders and files are not deleted because the code after the assert is not executed. This also sabotage the other tests because I use the same name of files and folders for all of them. Then I have to manually remove all those files to be able to test correctly again.

I thought of using fixtures but I don't think it is a good solution because, as I said, it test for different paths creation, it doesn't have a generic case. I would have to create individual fixtures for each test and this doesn't seem to be the best approach to this.

Here is one of my tests that that has this problem:

```py
def test_alocate_file_three_level_path(root_path):
    # creates files in root
    file_path1 = os.path.join(root_path, 'test1.pdf')
    Path(file_path1).touch()
    # creates path for test
    test_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'Downloads', 'path1', 'path2','path3','test1.pdf')
    # function alocate the file to folders
    func_aux.alocate_file('path1', 'path2', 'path3', 'test1.pdf')
    # check if the file is there
    assert os.path.isfile(test_path) == True
    # remove the created file and folders
    remove_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'Downloads', 'path1')
    shutil.rmtree(remove_path)
```

I want to know if the only way I can **guarantee** that all my folders and files created for test purposes are deleted is using specific fixtures for each test or there is a way where I can execute always the code after the assert **even with AssertionError**

Comment: Why cant' you do `if not os.path.isfile(test_path):` then execute whatever clean up code you need if this is the case, then do `raise AssertionError`?

Comment: I was trying here and this is the best way? Because, If I understand what you propose, I create this if statament: When false I delete the files and raise the error, if true, "assert True" (how I do that?) and also remove the files, repeating the code?

Comment: Your assertions would be in different branches of an `if`/`else` so you could still assert that the existence of the file were `True` in the `else` branch (though I don't know how useful this is) and then continue as you currently are. The only relevant part of my suggestion is being able to delay the raising of `AssertionError` until you have done whatever clean-up you need. I don't really do a lot of unittesting so I couldn't tell you if this was the _best_ way.

Comment: No, the fixtures _are_ the correct way to go here. Otherwise, you are polluting the test with the setup/teardown code which makes it pretty fragile. Use the `tmpdir` fixture to generate the `root_path`, `pytest` will then create a temporary directory before the test and cleanup it afterwards automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hoefling suggested, I implemented a fixture that creates a temporary directory. Modifying the code that I provided in the post, ended like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def temp_dir(root_path):
    down_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'Downloads', 'temp_dir')
    os.makedirs(down_path)
    yield down_path
    shutil.rmtree(down_path)


def test_alocate_file_three_level_path(root_path, temp_dir):
    # creates files in root
    file_path1 = os.path.join(root_path, 'test1.pdf')
    Path(file_path1).touch()
    # creates path for test
    test_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'path1', 'path2','path3','test1.pdf')
    # function alocate the file to folders
    func_aux.alocate_file('temp_dir', 'path1', 'path2', 'path3', 'test1.pdf')
    # check if the file is there
    assert os.path.isfile(test_path) == True
```

This garantee, in the end of the tests, that all the auxiliary files were deleted.  For those who don't understand what is going on, the fixture is executed until the yield. After that, the tests receive its value and do its job. Independet of *AssertionError*, when the test end, it gets back to the fixture and run the code after the yield.

Comment: What I meant was the [`tmpdir`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-tmpdir-fixture) fixture already available in `pytest` so you don't have to reimplement it yourself. However, glad you got the idea of fixtures!

Answer (score 4):

You could manage this with a simple `try... finally` block, since `assert` raises an AssertionError if the assertion is not verified:

```
x = 1

try:
    assert x == 0
finally:
    print("this code will always run")
```

Comment: Or `with`, which more closely fits the expected use case.

Comment: The `except` clause is not needed. In fact to maintain the usual behavior that the test fails with an `AssertionError`, one would not want to handle the `AssertionError` (or would want to re-raise it). In any case, the clean up code in the `finally` clause will be executed.

Comment: @aichao yes, you're right, I'll edit my answer